# 'su' command doesn't work for AD users

Tags: linux, active-directory, authentication

I want to have AD users to log in my Linux machine. I have added a CentOS 6.7 machine to an AD domain and all  things look ok.
I can execute 'kinit' command without error and 'wbinfo' works fine and shows to me all AD users and groups. Also I can get information about my users using 'id' command.
The problem is I cannot execute this command: 'su domain_user' and get error:

```
$ su domain_user
Password: 
Access is denied
su: incorrect password
```

In the same time I can login to this Linux machine using this account via SSH.

How is it possible? 
Thank for your help.

Comment: Are you SuperUser when executing the `su` command?

Comment: No, I am not a super user, but I can run this command from a super user session without password at all. But I thought it should work from all sessions.

Comment: Correct. Root does not need to enter a password to become a different user. Did you previously create a password for this user?

Comment: No, I didn't create a passpord for this use on a local machine. I want to use all exist users from a 'domain admins' group.

Answer (score 1):

I added the file /etc/security/pam_winbind.conf
And now it works fine.

```
# cat /etc/security/pam_winbind.conf
[global]
debug = no
debug_state = no
try_first_pass = yes
krb5_auth = yes
krb5_cache_type = FILE
cached_login = yes
silent = no
mkhomedir = yes
```